# R data.table - best option for Cartesian join

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for simple syntax for data.table's cartesian join e.g. I am using as below to get 1024 row in c_join but it requires to convert data.table to data.frame

```
d1 <- data.table(mtcars)
d2 <- data.table(mtcars)
c_join <- setDT(merge(x=as.data.frame(d1), y=as.data.frame(d2), by=NULL))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `CJ`

```
c_join2 <- do.call(cbind, Map(CJ, d1, d2))
dim(c_join2)
#[1] 1024   22
dim(c_join)
#[1] 1024   22
```

---

If we need the suffix `.x`, `.y` as in 'c_join'

```
c_join3 <-  do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) CJ(x = x, y = y), d1, d2))
```

Comment: Thanks, it created <column>.V1 and <column>.V2 for each column. Is there any option to avoid that.

Comment: @R007 If I check the `c_join` output, it creates suffix `.x` and `.y`.  Do you want to replace it with `.x` and `.y`